# error string subscript out of range c++

Tags: c++, loops

i have a guessed name game. and i have a problem with this function. in the nested loop if the user entered a wrong letter it gives me this error:

line: 1440
expression: string subscript out of range

this is the function:

```
void Play(int selection, int FArraySize, int  MArraySize,string Female[], string Male[])//Receive the selected name category array and its size and implements the game logic as shown in the sample run. Uses function GetRandomName(…).
{
    int MAX_TRIES = 4;
    int m = 0;
    int x=0;
    int j=0;
    ofstream ofFile;
    ifstream InFile;
    int num_of_wrong_guesses=0;
    char letter;
    string GuessedName;
    GuessedName = GetRandomName(selection, FArraySize, MArraySize, Female, Male);

    cout << "Guess the following name:" << endl;


    for(int y = 0; y < GuessedName.length(); y++){
        cout << "?";
        j++;
    }

    cout << "\nEnter a guess letter? or * to enter the entire name" << endl;
    cin >> letter;

    int i =0;

    for ( int count = 0 ; count <= MAX_TRIES ; count++)
    {
        while (i <= j)
        {

            if (letter ==  GuessedName[i])
            {
                i = m;
                cout << letter << " exists in the name";
                cout << "\nyou have " << MAX_TRIES << " remaining guess attemps... "<< endl;
                break;
            }
            if (i == j)
            {
                cout <<"Sorry! " << letter << " dose not exist in the name";
                cout << "\nyou have " << MAX_TRIES-- << " remaining guess attemps... ";
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }

        cout << "\nGuess the following name:" << endl;
    for(int y = 0; y < GuessedName.length(); y++){
        cout << "?";
        j++;
    }
        cin >> letter;
    }
    return;
}
```

hope you can help me.

Comment: You are looping until i = j. This will make the first if compare to GuessedName[j], which is off limits.

Comment: Also, those loops that print question marks need not be there.  All you need is a single line: `cout << string(GuessName.length(), '?');`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i need them to calculate j.

Comment: @MajdaAlrashdi You don't need loops to calculate `j`.  `j += GuessName.length();`

Comment: sorry, you haven't 1440 lines in your code post.  [] operator doesn't have array bound check (there's a method for that) so I'm lost.  Where's the line with the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while (i <= j)` should be `while (i < j)`.

Otherwise `GuessedName[i]` will try to access out-of-bounds when `i == j`. `j - 1` is the index of the last letter.